# Shiro matching credentialsMatcher and user password creation not matching

Tags: java, security, shiro, sha256

I am using shiro as authentication for my java 1.8 application. My user creation will sha256 and salt.

Shiro will only match passwords when they are exact in the database an entered. For example if the database password was in plaintext and was 'password' and i entered 'password' it would work.

If i entered 'password' when the password is encrypted in the database it does not match and will fail.

How do i get shiro to create a sha256 and salted password from what was entered so the passwords will match?

My user creation code

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = 
                    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("e");

            EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            com.e.dto.User user = new com.e.dto.User();

            DefaultPasswordService a = new DefaultPasswordService();
            password = a.encryptPassword(password);

            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(password);

            em.persist(user);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

shiro.ini

```
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password from user where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role from userroles where userID = (select id FROM user WHERE username = ?)

ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = root
ds.password = password
ds.databaseName = myDatabase
jdbcRealm.dataSource= $ds

credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = true
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 10000
credentialsMatcher.hashSalted = true
```

New Users password

```
$shiro1$SHA-256$500000$xRvz5dByhvAtFG7VHlCjHA==$xxakvEZdBF6cI+UmyR1OY098tAlscOKhpwQuT7THijw=
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the passwords to match the DefaultPasswordService object must be created in the ini and then set as `org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher` `passwordService` value

https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/PasswordService.html

```
passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
# configure the passwordService to use the settings you desire

passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService
```